# Eclipse RCP Buildtool

Tags: maven, ant, build, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I want to automate the Build Process of an existing RCP application with an own target platform.
Now I can't decide between Ant and Maven ore maybe there is a better tool?!

The tool should be easy to set up, and should run JUnit and SWTBot Tests.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/) is a good way to build Eclipse plug-ins / applications :

> Tycho is focused on a Maven-centric, manifest-first approach to building Eclipse plug-ins, features, update sites, RCP applications and OSGi bundles. Tycho is a set of Maven plugins and extensions for building Eclipse plugins and OSGi bundles with Maven

Comment: I use tycho and it is great! Several Eclipse projects now use it. It can also be combined with Continuous Integration tools!

Comment: Thx...Cool, means Tycho takes the informations out of the manifest from Eclipse?!

Comment: @Orri - yes, the build is based in the most part on the plugin manifests, feature files etc. You still need to have a basic Maven  structure in place though.

Comment: Do you know a good Tutorial for a OSGI Build with Maven Tycho?

Comment: The Tycho documentation - http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php - is a good starting point.

Comment: Ok I got maven and Tycho but I have some Problems getting tycho known of my target platform. My targetplatform is a seperate file with .jar plugins...the only way i could manage some target-platform-dependancies is to make eclipse indigo as a p2 repository-> but that dos not solf all dependancies :-(   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267371/tycho-target-platform

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

This tools are continuous integration (CI) servers.

With help of `TeamCity`, for example, you can create project which run `Ant` targets or build application with `Maven` or you can use configuration with both `Maven` and `Ant`.

[This article](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/07/teamcity-creating-project-step-by-step.html) is how to create project in `TeamCity`. This [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/index.html#Build_Infrastructure) is about of TeamCity's main features.

The `TeamCity` supports JUnit, you can [read info](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/supported_platforms.html) about others supported tools and platfoms.

The another tool is [Luntbuild](http://luntbuild.javaforge.com/).

Comment: I know (CI)servers, that should be the goal of the hole project but one of the requirements of an CI server is a working build-tool. That is my first problem :-( At the moment we build our project out of Eclipse.

Comment: @Orri We are using `Maven` for building project and `Ant` for some deploying needs (custom tasks). We have `TeamCity's` project that build project and run `JUnit` tests with `Maven` and after that it runs several `Ant` scripts. We run this project by setting scheduler in TeamCity or manually

Comment: @Orri Some times ago we used Luntbuild: http://luntbuild.javaforge.com/ for the same purpose

Comment: Thx...The Thing with Maven and Ant is my goal at the moment...Build with Maven and Ant for some commandos executed under Maven...And how do you get Target Platform known in Maven?

Answer (score 1):

here, a [tycho tutorial](http://goo.gl/X1sK)
for some reason, i couldn't add this as a comment. weird
ps: I'm using tycho with hudson, and this is GREAT!